# Xcode: xcode crashes when trying to open project settings

Tags: ios, xcode

This is a bug that's really getting on my nerves...

Whenever I try to open the project settings for one of my projects, xcode crashes with this report:

> Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 4H512 UNCAUGHT
>   EXCEPTION (NSUnknownKeyException): [<__NSCFConstantString
>   0x7fff783e0fa0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key CFBundleTypeName. UserInfo: {
>       NSTargetObjectUserInfoKey = "";
>       NSUnknownUserInfoKey = CFBundleTypeName; } Hints:    0: Replacement view is installing:

I created an entire new project and c/p the files from my bugged project into it. It happened again. I have Xcode 5 installed on my computer so I accidentally run my project in Xcode 5, setting certain Xcode 5 specific settings and breaking compatability with my Xcode 4.6.1.

Please help...

Comment: Are you able to just restore to a previous commit assuming you were using some type of source control software for your project?

Comment: I agree with Ralph, archive your changes, restore to a previous commit. Reapply your changes, but do not change the `pbxproj` file. Or just revert the `pbxproj` to a previous version.

Answer (score 0):

if you have open your project in xcode5 and then try to open the project in xcode4, all the nibs files get updated according new xcode and it will lead to crash as it is incompatible with older xcode4.

Same problem happened with me also,
What I have done to solve mine problem.
1. Remove references of all nibs from the project. or even move to trash by taking backup somewhere.
2. Now, in xcode4 create new empty nib file and open the corresponding nib in xcode5, copy the view and paste in xcode4.
3. do this for all the nibs and try to build again

hope it helps